# Isssue with display data from database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I use framework:
CodeIgniter

I try display values from enrol table. Connetcion with DB working correct etc. Because standard app function in this way working correct. I try add my custom own code but something went wrong and result is empty.

I try combinate in this way:

```
<?php
$enrol_history = $this->db->get_where('enrol', array('active_shop' => $active_shop, 'monthly_subscription_fee' => $monthly_subscription_fee))->row_array();
?>

<?php echo $active_shop['active_shop']; ?>
<?php echo $enrol_history['monthly_subscription_fee']; ?>

<?php echo $active_shop ?>
<?php echo $monthly_subscription_fee ?>
```

Everytime empty result.

[image]

update:
I also try:
Crud_model.php

```
public function get_installation_details($monthly_subscription_fee = "")
    {
        return $this->db->get_where('enrol', array('monthly_subscription_fee' => $monthly_subscription_fee));
    }
```

code:

```
<?php $installation_details = $this->crud_model->get_installation_details($monthly_subscription_fee)->row_array(); ?>
 <?php echo $installation_details['monthly_subscription_fee']; ?>
```

update:

```
<?php 

$enrol_history = $this->db->get_where('enrol', array('active_shop' => $enrol['active_shop'], 'monthly_subscription_fee' => $enrol['monthly_subscription_fee'],))->row_array();

 ?>

 <?php echo $enrol['monthly_subscription_fee']; ?>
<?php echo $enrol['active_shop']; ?>
```

This is correct. Because in admin panel I can get in this way this values from DB. But in frontend I cannot do it...

Comment: `$enrol_history = $this->db->get_where('enrol', array('active_shop' => $active_shop, 'monthly_subscription_fee' => $monthly_subscription_fee))->row_array();` `var_dump` `$active_shop` and `$monthly_subscription_fee` to make sure they are correct

Comment: @Canah can you please check my update

Comment: No. I mean you should var_dum those values to make sure they are right? From the image, `active_shop` must be 1 and `monthly_subscription_fee` must be 40. If they are, `$enrol_history = $this->db->get_where('enrol', array('active_shop' => $enrol['active_shop'], 'monthly_subscription_fee' => $enrol['monthly_subscription_fee'],))->row_array();` will return the value you want